# Get if pull request passed all required status checks using GitHub API

Tags: github, github-api, github-enterprise

I need to check via GitHub API if a pull request passed all *required* status checks. I use GitHub Enterprise 2.8 at this moment.

I know that I can get all status checks for last commit (following `statuses_url` in pull request). However, I don't know which status checks are set up to be required in a given repository. This is my main problem.

I also need to aggregate these status checks, group them by `context` and take latest in each context. It's ok, but seems to be reimplementation of logic, that GitHub performs internally when decides if a pull request can be merged.

For my case, it would be ideal to have something like `can_be_merged` in pull request fields, which meaning is `mergeable && all required status checks passed && approved`, but as far as I know there is no such field.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I was about to post almost the same question. I've been pouring over the docs to figure this out, to no avail...

Comment: Nope, I've ended up hardcoding required status checks in my app :(

Answer (score 5):

Finally solved this! You actually need to get the information off the protected branch, not off the check itself. Here are some API details: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/branches/#list-required-status-checks-contexts-of-protected-branch.

So the flow to solve this is:

1. Check if the base branch for the PR is protected, and if so;
2. Use the above endpoint to determine which checks are required;
3. Compare the checks on the latest PR commit to the required checks determined in step 2.

Comment: I have a slight variation of this: I want to get the required checks _which are GitHub Actions_ and this seems to complicate things a lot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75063703/github-api-find-status-of-required-checks-on-a-pull-request-towards-protected-b

Answer (score 0):

Based on @moustachio's answer, if you are using v4 graphql API, you may use

```
    pullRequest(...) {
      baseRef {
        refUpdateRule {
          requiredStatusCheckContexts
        }
      }
    }
```

to get the same info without additional API request