# GitHub API: find status of required checks on a pull request towards protected branch, which are github actions

Tags: github-actions, github-api

Context:

- I have a PR `12345` towards protected branch (`master`)
- This branch is set up to `require` two jobs for merging: one from GitLab CI `gitlab/some-required-test`, and one from GitHub Action `some-required-github-action`
- Apart from that I have a ton of non-required jobs in each GL and GH. *I don't care about those.*
- **I want to check via GitHub API if the PR has passed all `required` checks only.**

This is similar to [Get if pull request passed all required status checks using GitHub API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44410551/get-if-pull-request-passed-all-required-status-checks-using-github-api) but **in particular I want to know if the *ones from github-actions*** have passed which seems very complicated.

The ones from GitLab are easy, by querying `https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/commits/REFNAME/status` I get a reasonably shaped response with all necessary info. But it's only having GitLab check, not GitHub actions.

```
{
  state: 'pending',
  statuses: [
    {
        state: 'success',
        context: 'gitlab/check-1',
    },
    {
        state: 'pending',
        context: 'gitlab/check-2',
    }
  ]
  ...
}
```

So, first, I figured that by querying an endpoint for branch protections, I can figure out the required checks. So far so good:

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/ORG/REPO/branches/PROTECTED_BRANCH_NAME/protection/required_status_checks 

{
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/ORG/REPO/branches/PROTECTED_BRANCH_NAME/protection/required_status_checks",
    "strict": false,
    "contexts": [
      "gitlab/some-required-test",
      "some-required-github-action"
    ],
    "contexts_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/ORG/REPO/branches/PROTECTED_BRANCH_NAME/protection/required_status_checks/contexts",
    "checks": [
      {
        "context": "gitlab/some-required-test",
        "app_id": null
      },
      {
        "context": "some-required-github-action",
        "app_id": 15368
      }
    ]
}
```

(app_id 15368 corresponds to "GitHub Actions" app).

Let's now check the status of the checks:

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/ORG/REPO/commits/PR_BRANCH/check-suites


{
  "total_count": 10,
  "check_suites": [{
      "id": 10271137035,
      "node_id": "CS_kwDOCf2-888AAAACZDUdKQ",
      "head_branch": "BRANCHNAME",
      "head_sha": "936b3031077ba7b71e0233fec23783ca0d3ed93e",
      "status": "completed",
      "conclusion": "success",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/check-suites/10271137065",
      "before": "8e579556a3909a0d25dbdd34e6ff0a9535653848",
      "after": "936b3031077ba7b71e0233fec23783ca0d3ed93e",
      "pull_requests": [...],
      "app": {
        "id": 15368,
        "slug": "github-actions",
        "node_id": "MDM6QXBwMTUzNjg=",
        "owner": {
          "login": "github",
          ...
        },
        "name": "GitHub Actions",
        "description": "Automate your workflow from idea to production",
        "external_url": "https://help.github.com/en/actions",
        "html_url": "https://github.com/apps/github-actions",
        "created_at": "2018-07-30T09:30:17Z",
        "updated_at": "2019-12-10T19:04:12Z",
        "permissions": {
          ...
        },
        "events": [
          ...
        ]
      },
      "created_at": "2023-01-09T21:36:29Z",
      "updated_at": "2023-01-09T21:38:16Z",
      "rerequestable": true,
      "runs_rerequestable": false,
      "latest_check_runs_count": 1,
      "check_runs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/check-suites/10271137035/check-runs",
      "head_commit": {
        "id": "936b3031077ba7b71e0233fec23783ca0d3ed93e",
        "tree_id": "4f341091f31a419915f6d8b70f42febdd115ee2f",
        "message": "COMMIT MESSAGE",
        "timestamp": "2023-01-09T21:36:12Z",
        "author": {...},
        "committer": {...}
      },
      "repository": {...}
  }, ...]
}
```

I get a large array of `check_suites` but the response is only moderately helpful:
By checking `app.id` / `app.slug` + `status` / `conclusion` I can see that *some GitHub action* has completed, but without details whether it is required, and what is its name.

I figured I can check `.latest_check_runs_count` and if > 0, check `check_runs_url`:

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/ORG/REPO/check-suites/10271137035/check-runs

{
  "total_count": 1,
  "check_runs": [
    {
      "id": 10536722916,
      "name": "some-required-github-action",
      "node_id": "CR_kwDOCf2-888AAAACdAmh5A",
      "head_sha": "936b3031077ba7b71e0233fec23783ca0d3ed93e",
      "external_id": "373218f8-38be-52de-27db-c87f3616be12",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/ORG/REPO/check-runs/10536722916",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/ORG/REPO/actions/runs/3877963115/jobs/6613591600",
      "details_url": "https://github.com/ORG/REPO/actions/runs/3877963115/jobs/6613591600",
      "status": "completed",
      "conclusion": "success",
      "started_at": "2023-01-09T21:36:38Z",
      "completed_at": "2023-01-09T21:38:14Z",
      "output": {
        "title": null,
        "summary": null,
        "text": null,
        "annotations_count": 0,
        "annotations_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/ORG/REPO/check-runs/10536722916/annotations"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then I can inspect `check_runs[i].name` and if it's one of `required` ones obtained earlier, check `check_runs[i].status` / `check_runs[i].conclusion`. (In the example, it's `"some-required-github-action"` which I was looking for)

But for this I have to do N requests, one for each item in `.check_suites` from previous step where `"app.slug": "github-actions"`.

This sounds very convoluted. Is there a simpler way?